# Managing files while using floyd

Tags: python

How can I use data files which are on my PC when using Floyd?

after running:

```
floyd init
floyd run --gpu --env tensorflow-1.3 "python model.py"
```

I get in logs that:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\barte\Desktop\Projects\tf\drugs review\drugsComTest_raw.csv')
```

this sample doesn't work and i get such logs:

```
2019-10-26 09:21:49 PSTStarting container...
2019-10-26 09:21:49 PST
################################################################################
2019-10-26 09:21:49 PSTRun Output:
2019-10-26 09:21:49 PSTStarting services.
2019-10-26 09:21:51 PSTUsing TensorFlow backend.
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTTraceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "model.py", line 17, in <module>
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTdata = pd.read_csv('drugs review\drugsComTest_raw.csv',usecols=['review','rating'])
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTreturn _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 405, in _read
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTparser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 764, in __init__
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTself._make_engine(self.engine)
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 985, in _make_engine
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTself._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1605, in __init__
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTself._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 394, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:4209)
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFile "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 710, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:8873)
2019-10-26 09:22:03 PSTFileNotFoundError: File b'drugs review\\drugsComTest_raw.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists but on my PC, I don't know how to make it available on Floyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the file in the directory you `floyd init`. It will then be copied to the Floyd hub.